# How mobile app WiFiKill can cut off internet access to neighbor devices?

Tags: wifi, android

There is a program for android- WifiKill which disables wifi internet access of some neighbor peers connected to the same wifi AP. How does this program work? ARP poisoning or some other techniques? Is there a similar one for laptop?  Is there a way to prevent such attack? Link to [WifiKill](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1282900).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WifiKill uses ARP poisoning:

> The app works only with rooted phones and works, similarly to FaceNiff, by spoofing ARP replies to trick other devices on the network into thinking your Android phone is the router. WiFiKill then drops all their network packets. To the victims, it still appears as if they are connected to the network, but the internet just appears to have stalled.

[source](http://lifehacker.com/5853775/kick-other-devices-off-a-wi+fi-network-with-wifikill-on-android)

A similar program is [Ettercap](http://ettercap.sourceforge.net/).